# Unable to extractFieldwith SMT transformation in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm not able to perform SMT transformation "ExtractField" in order to extract field from key struct to a simple long value with an Oracle database. It works fine with a Postgres database.

I tried to use "ReplaceField" SMT to rename the key and it works fine. I suspect a problem in the class "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField" on schema handling to get the field. Schema handling seems to work differently between "ReplaceField" and "ExtractField".

Oracle database version: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.8.0.0.0
Debezium connect: 1.6
Kafka version: 2.7.0
Instanclient basic (Oracle client and drivers): 21.3.0.0.0

I got an "Unknown field ID_MYTABLE":

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded
> in error handler at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:339)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:264)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ***Unknown field: ID_MYTABLE***
> org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField.apply(***ExtractField.java:65***)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
> ... 11 more

Here is my configuration of my Kafka connector:

```
{
  "name": "oracle-connector",  
  "config": {   
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector", 
    "tasks.max": "1", 
    "database.server.name": "serverName", 
    "database.user": "c##dbzuser", 
    "database.password": "dbz", 
    "database.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:...", 
    "database.dbname": "dbName", 
    "database.pdb.name": "PDBName", 
    "database.connection.adapter": "logminer", 
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", 
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.data", 
    "schema.include.list": "mySchema", 
    "table.include.list": "mySchema.myTable", 
    "log.mining.strategy": "online_catalog", 
    "snapshot.mode": "initial", 
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false", 
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter", 
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true", 
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081", 
    "transforms": "unwrap,route,extractField",
    "transforms.extractField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key", 
    "transforms.extractField.field": "ID_MYTABLE", 
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState", 
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter", 
    "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)", 
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$1_$2_$3" 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Verify that there's no uppercase/lowercase mismatch in the name of the table and the column. Remember that by default, all identifiers (table names, column names, ...) in Oracle are uppercase, unless you enclose them in double-quotes. So check in the db what you have.

Comment: Hi @gsalem, thank's for the answer. I already check it out. Furthermore, I noticed that with the "ReplaceField" SMT operation it works fine with the same field value.

Comment: Well, I have no knowledge of the kafka connector at all, so no idea what this SMT operation is. One way is to enable trace in the DB, and check what the connector is doing there, like if there's an ORA-... error somewhere in the trace.

Comment: I have the same problem: "ReplaceField" SMT operation works fine with the same field value and "ExtractField" returns " Unknown field:"

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you configure SMTs for any connector, including Debezium,  transformation is applied to every record that the connector emits. That includes change event messages that might not have the retrieved data and might not have the necessary fields.
To solve this, you need to apply your SMTs selectively to only a specific subset of change event messages generated by Debezium using SMT predicates.

The official documentation is located [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/applying-transformations-selectively.html).

In your specific case, you could apply the SMT only to the output topic for that specific database table it would look something like this:

```
# Create a predicate that matches your output 
predicates: topicNameMatch
predicates.topicNameMatch.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches
predicates.topicNameMatch.pattern: *output topic name goes here*

# Your logic to extract the field from the key
transforms.extractField.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractField.field: ID_MYTABLE

# This references the predicate above
transforms.extractField.predicate: topicNameMatch
```

There are other predicates located in the documentation listed above if the topic name matching doesn't work for you.